# How to have a method with multiple objects?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, methods, header

I have a program I am trying to make that has a super class, Person and subclass, Student and trying to compare when they are equal based on their birthday and name. I got it correct, but on the prompt I am trying to to solve I get an error where the autograder is: "Testing a Student and Student are the same, even if grade is different" and the expected result is true, but I keep getting false. The program works when comparing a person and student and when comparing a person and person, not student and student and I'm not sure why.

Main Class:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Person's name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Person's birthday: ");
        String birthday = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the Student's name: ");
        String studentName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Student's birthday: ");
        String studentBirthday = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Student's grade: ");
        int grade = in.nextInt();

        Person p1 = new Person(name, birthday);
        Student p2 = new Student(studentName, studentBirthday, grade);

        System.out.println("Same: " + p1.equals(p1, p2));
    }
}
```

Superclass:

```java
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String birthday;

    public Person(String name, String birthday) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //Create a equals method here
    public boolean equals(Person p1, Person p2) {
        boolean isEqual = false;
        if ((p1.getName()).equals(p2.getName()) 
                && (p1.getBirthday()).equals(p2.getBirthday())) {
            isEqual = true;
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```java
public class Student extends Person {
    //Instance variable
    private int grade;

    //Subclass constructor
    public Student(String name, String birthday, int grade) {
        super(name, birthday);
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the method equals for the instance p1 of person. for  write a correct method write this method like this:

```java
public boolean equals(Person p2) {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    if ((this.getName()).equals(p2.getName())
            && (this.getBirthday()).equals(p2.getBirthday())) {
        isEqual = true;
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

And when you invoke this method, do this:

```java
p1.equals(p2)
```